# StandadScaler and Pipeline function usage syntax

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would like to know what exactly does the "estimator" variable do and how it changes along the flow of the program.

Similarly, please explain the role of the "Pipeline" function over here.

I'm having a very difficult time trying to understand it from the Scikit-learn website.

```
# evaluate baseline model with standardized dataset
numpy.random.seed(seed)
estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp', KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_baseline, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=5, verbose=0)))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(y=encoded_Y, n_folds=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, encoded_Y, cv=kfold)
print("Standardized: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

Comment: Did you read the user-guide on pipeline? It's not that hard. Pipeline is just building one object (=transformer, which supports the basic operations like fit, transform, predict) from multiple transformers (e.g. preprocessing + classification in your case).

Comment: I'm unable to relate the documentation to the implementation in this code. It would be really great if you could help me understand what exactly is happening over here with the StandardScalar and the Pipeline functions.